# Starting an intent from a sliding menu item

Tags: android

I have this class that defines my sliding menu items and I want to start different intents (not fragments, but activities) when some of them has been clicked.

```
public class RggarbSlidingMenu extends SherlockListFragment{

    String[] list_contents = {
        "My Profile",
        "My Items",
        "Messages",
        "Notifications",
        "Items Feed",
        "People Feed",
        "Places Feed",
        "Privacy Policy",
        "Terms of Service",
        "Settings",
        "Log Out"
    };

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState){
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.list, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list_contents));
    }
    @Override
    public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id){

        if (position == 0) {
            Intent signup = new Intent(RggarbSlidingMenu.this, Signup.class); 
            startActivity(signup);
        } else if (position == 1) {
        } else if (position == 2) {
        } else if (position == 3) {
        } else if (position == 4) {
        }

    }

}
```

but on the following lines

```
if (position == 0) {
        Intent signup = new Intent(this, MyProfile.class); 
        startActivity(signup);
```

I get this error:

```
The constructor Intent(RggarbSlidingMenu, Class<Signup>) is undefined
```

How can I start an intent from here?

**Also, how can I use a selector for items, that is not their position, because this confuses me, I would like to select them by their name instead?**

Comment: Please replace this `Intent signup = new Intent(this, MyProfile.class);` with `Intent signup = new Intent(getActivity(), MyProfile.class);`

Comment: I didn't get your second question what do you want exactly??

Comment: I dont want to determine the item clicked by its position in the if else if statement, but by its name/text

Comment: @J. Kowalski In your second question, Are you asking about how to get clicked item text?

Comment: well, kinda. and use it in the if else statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please replace this `Intent signup = new Intent(this, MyProfile.class);` with `Intent signup = new Intent(getActivity(), MyProfile.class);`

For second question,

```
if((((TextView)v.findViewById(android.R.id.text1)).getText().toString()).equals("Profile"))
{
    //Do your task here
}
```

Comment: Thank you, you were the first to answer so I think its fair to accept your answer (when Im allowed to) How about my second question that is in bold? :)

Comment: @J. Kowalski Check my edited answer for your second question. Do you get what you required?

Comment: where do you get this header_text_view from?

Comment: thanks, but what is text1? How do I know what it corresponds to?

Comment: @J.Kowalski You have used android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1 layout with your array adapter this layout has textview with the name text1. You can find that layout within your SDK folder android-sdk\platforms\android-7\data\res\layout

Answer (score 1):

Change this line

```
Intent signup = new Intent(this, MyProfile.class); 
    startActivity(signup);
```

into

```
Intent signup = new Intent(getActivity(), MyProfile.class); 
    startActivity(signup);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to replace this :

```
Intent signup = new Intent(this, MyProfile.class);
```

To :

```
 Intent signup = new Intent(getActivity(), MyProfile.class);
```